# Azure Batch job via function triggers

Tags: azure, triggers, cloud

I am relatively new to Azure and hence my question might sound a bit daft. I will ask anyway :)

I intend to use `function trigger` (Blob trigger) to kick start Azure batch run and wondering:

1. if this is really a good idea
2. if so, could anyone share an example code or direct me to one doing the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077954/access-azure-batch-from-an-azure-function) you could refer to. If possible, please provide more details such as what the language you use and what is the function runtime and so on.

Comment: I am using C# and what I would like to happen is, to auto start Azure batch whenever, blob trigger is caused as the result of a blob being uploaded. I hope this helps.